# How do you convert a number to radians? I know the that the answer is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ but how do you solve it?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have no idea how to solve a number to radians, the question is "convert to radians $270$" and the answer is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, I got the answer from a friend but I don't know how to solve the problem, I need to know because I have a test on that.

Comment: When converting to radians, express your answers in terms of $\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $180^\circ$ in the sweep of a semicircle, which is $\pi\;\mathrm{radian}$.

$\therefore 180^\circ = \pi \;\mathrm{radian} \implies 270^\circ=\frac{\pi\times 270}{180} \;\mathrm{radian}= \frac{3\pi}2\;\mathrm{radian}$

Comment: Thnx for the edit.It is more clear now.@Graham

Answer (score 1):

$360$ degrees is one revolution or $2\pi$ radians.
and $0$ degrees is $0$ radians.
The relation is linear.